# Grails[Groovy],How to get list of all methods a class has with out those inherited?

Tags: grails, groovy

I am using this to collect all methods a class has:

grailsApplication.getMainContext().getBean("className").metaClass.methods*.name

But this returns all the methods *including the inherited ones*, **how can I filter only the methods owned by the class**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will give you the list of method names filtered to include only methods belonging to only the declaring class(`SomeClass` in this example):

```
SomeClass sc = new SomeClass()
List<String> declaringClassOnlyMethods = sc.metaClass.methods.findAll { MetaMethod method ->
    if(method.declaringClass.name == sc.class.name) {
        method.name
    }
}
```